How to Use the Background behaviour in flutter
I have Added the tpa through functionality and the dragging functionality in my flutter app recently i am facing this issue in the flutter code :-

There's no constant named 'none' in 'OverlayFlag'.

isActive = await OverlayPopUp.showOverlay(
                        width: 300,
                        height: 300,
                        closeWhenTapBackButton: false,
                        isDraggable: !isLocked,
                        backgroundBehavior: isLocked ? OverlayFlag.tapThrough : OverlayFlag.none,
                      );

I am getting the error in this Line
backgroundBehavior: isLocked ? OverlayFlag.tapThrough : OverlayFlag.none,
